# Можно ли обрабатывать нажатия callback_buttons бота, но из общей группы?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, pyrogram, telegram

Есть бот. После приёма некого заказа от пользователя, он посылает это сообщение в общий чат-группу операторов, прикрепляя к этому сообщения callback-buttons.

Хочу, чтобы операторы могли нажать на эти кнопки, и чтобы бот их обрабатывал. Я прикрепил эти кнопки, но при нажатие на них ничего не происходит.

Отправляю клавиатуру с кнопками так:

```
keyboard = InlineKeyboard()
callback_data_cmd = f"cmd1:{data['order_id']}"
keyboard.row(
    InlineButton('Test1', callback_data="{callback_data_cmd}:var1"),
)
keyboard.row(
    InlineButton('Test2', callback_data="{callback_data_cmd}:var2"),
    InlineButton('Test3', callback_data="{callback_data_cmd}:var3"),
    InlineButton('Test4', callback_data="{callback_data_cmd}:var4"),
)

client.send_message(_chat_id, "test", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Почему ничего не происходит? Это технически не поддерживается Телеграммом?

В целом, эти кнопки работают, но только если разместить в чате самого бота с пользователем.